# How to enforce candle.exe FIPS with -fips or <FipsCompliant>true</FipsCompliant>?

Tags: wix

Our systems require the FIPS group policy to be enabled. When trying to get around the following error:

```
candle.exe(0,0): error CNDL0308: The Federal Information Processing Standard (FIPS) appears to be enabled on the machine. You must either disable FIPS or use FIPS-compliant security algorithms to generate IDs by passing the -fips command-line switch or by setting true in your .wixproj project.
```

Where exactly should I be using the `-fips` parameter, or how should I use the true tag in my wixproj file?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `FipsCompliant` property as `true` to your .wixproj. For example,

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <FipsCompliant>true</FipsCompliant>
</PropertyGroup>
```